# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/function/Predicate

Tags: java, windows, maven, ubuntu, jar

I have created a jar file using

```
mvn assembly:assembly -DdescriptorId=jar-with-dependencies
```

and I run it on windows and it works fine and works as expected. Then I run it on Ubuntu and it gives the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/function/Predicate
at Maxima_ImageJ.run(Maxima_ImageJ.java:13)
at Maxima_ImageJ.main(Maxima_ImageJ.java:27)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.util.function.Predicate
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 2 more
```

I have no idea why it works differently in Windows and Ubuntu. If someone do, please help. Is it related to the versions of java?

Comment: What version of java are you running? This will not work for jre version less than 1.8(java 8)

Comment: I think the default in my Ubuntu machine is 1.7.0_75. What will not run on jre version less than 1.8?

Comment: java.util.function.Predicate was introduced as part of java 8 so the code will not work for jre < 1.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your java version by using below command.

readlink -f $(which java)

If it is less than 1.8, then you have to update Java_Version.

One way is to edit in .bashrc file.

Answer (score 4):

Set class path to Java 1.8 as `java.util.function.Predicate` is part of JavaSE8 and will not be available in 1.7 some of the `set` commands to use before executing maven command.

```
set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin//UPTO Bin
set JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre8//Upto Root folder of JRE
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05//UPTO Root folder of JDK
```